# Regex remove string from Group

Tags: regex

Is it possible to do a remove match from a group?

Here is my string:

```
Current ACLs for resource `ResourcePattern(resourceType=TOPIC, name=aa-environment.topic-ok, patternType=LITERAL)`:

Current ACLs for resource `ResourcePattern(resourceType=TOPIC, name=bb-environment.topic-deleted - marked for deletion, patternType=LITERAL)`:
```

Today I have a regex:

```
^Current ACLs for resource \`ResourcePattern\(resourceType=(\w+), name=(\S+), patternType=(\w+)\)\`
```

This will give me a match on **Group 2** `aa-environment.topic-ok`.

What I'm looking for is to also have a match on `bb-environment.topic-deleted - marked for deletion` but without  `- marked for deletion`.

Output for **Group 2** should give:

- `aa-environment.topic-ok`
- `bb-environment.topic-deleted`

[Link to regex101 template](https://regex101.com/r/w0a4dy/1)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can write the pattern not allowing a comma until the next occurrence instead:

```
^Current ACLs for resource `ResourcePattern\(resourceType=(\w+), name=([^,]+), patternType=(\w+)\)`
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/3DUyik/1)

If you don't use `` ` `` as a delimiter, you don't have to escape it.